# django-simple-history track User from python shell

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

We are using django-simple-history to track changes in our models. All models have a `history = HistoricalRecords()` field. When making changes to a model from the python shell, the changes are tracked, however the `changed_by` field is saved as `None`. When changes are made in admin, the simple_history middleware grabs the User instance from whoever is logged in. Obviously in shell we don't have that. Is there any way to manually inject the User instance based on an existing Account object?

Unfortunately I'm not able to change any of these models, so I can't add any of the history user getters and setters to our models (project manager is very strict about refactoring and we also have a lot of models)

Comment: what do you mean by "manually inject the User instance based on an existing Account object"?

Comment: I might not be using the right terminology. You should be able to get the user from `HistoricalRecords.thread.request.user`, but in shell, local thread has no request attribute. I'm wondering if there is some way to attach it

Comment: But what user would you attach anyway? There’s no way to know.

Comment: We're running a script through shell from an external service (jenkins) which will have the user email, which corresponds to an account in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html#using-history-user-to-record-which-user-changed-a-model), for a particular object with history called `ObjectWithHistory`, you can set the history user on the object before saving like this:

```
o = ObjectWithHistory(*kwargs)
o._history_user = this_user
o.save()
```

Comment: oh dang, I think I must have misinterpreted what the docs were saying when I read earlier. thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. How does this solve the `shell` requirement? I don't want to manually specify the user, I want the shell to know which user I am

Answer (score 1):

### Using middleware

The [HistoryRequestMiddleware middleware](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html#recording-which-user-changed-a-model) automatically takes care of that, if you edit the database through django views

```
self.client.post(reverse("frontend:application_create"), data=data)
```

instead of directly in command line

```py
myapp.models.Application.objects.create(name='My application')
```

### Example (unit test)

Here is a unit test to find out which user changed a record (inspired by [django-simple-history unit tests](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/tests/tests/test_middleware.py)).

```py
# tests.py
class HistoryTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_changed_by(self):
        """Find out which user changed a record"""

        # First, let's create and log a user in
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("jimihendrix", password="pwtest")
        self.client.login(username="jimihendrix", password="pwtest")

        # Let's create a new entry
        data = {"name": "A new application", }
        response = self.client.post(reverse("frontend:application_create"), data=data)

        # This how you know who changed the record
        self.assertEqual(app1.history.earliest().history_user, user)
        self.assertEqual(app1.history.last().history_user, user)
        self.assertEqual(app1.history.first().history_user, user)

# urls.py
    # ...
    path('application/create/', old_views.ApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='application_create'),
    # ...

# models.py
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```